# How to inject DbContext into NRules class constructor?

Tags: c#, nrules

I am using NRules to define rules and trying to using interface inside NRules base class but something goes wrong and I get  "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" error.
Here is my Interface definition

```cs
{
    public interface ICalcDiscount
    {
        public void ApplyPoint(int point);
    }
    public class CalcDiscount:ICalcDiscount
    {
        private readonly UniContext _context;

       public CalcPoint(UniContext context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        public  void ApplyDiscount(int d)
        {
           _context.Discount.Add(new Discount{ CustomerId = 1, d= d});
           _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

NRule Class

```cs
 public class PreferredCustomerDiscountRule : Rule
    {
        private readonly ICalcDiscount _d;

        public PreferredCustomerDiscountRule(ICalcDiscount d)
        {
            _d = d;
        }
        public override void Define()
        {
            Book book = null;


            When()

                .Match(() => book);


            Then()
                .Do(ctx => _c.ApplyDiscount(10));

        }

    }
```

I have received an error when NRules begin load assembly
MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

```cs
 //Load rules
    var repository = new RuleRepository();
    repository.Load(x => x.From(typeof(PreferredCustomerDiscountRule).Assembly));//problem is here!
 //Compile rules
    var factory = repository.Compile();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you can't have a rule which has a constructor containing parameters.

You also should be resolving the dependency inside of the rule definition, as shown in [Rule Dependency](https://github.com/NRules/NRules/wiki/Rule-Dependencies) on the NRules wiki.

Your class should therefore be something like the following:

```
public class PreferredCustomerDiscountRule : Rule
    {
        public override void Define()
        {
            Book book = null;
            ICalcDiscount discountService = null;

            Dependency()
                .Resolve(() => discountService);

            When()
                .Match(() => book);


            Then()
                .Do(_ => discountService.ApplyDiscount(10));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hey @Nicholas, the does work, but one can not use the service to look up values to be used in the "When" condition. Do you know how to use a service as part of a query? see => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469249/property-injection-for-nrules-within-abp